# Is there a software tool to write contracts?

Tags: software

Is there a tool that you can write (for example) contracts with?

I have seen some people using LaTeX for it, but is everybody just using Microsoft Word and then formatting everything by hand for each document?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a question about the law.

Comment: This might be better on stack overflow or code golf, or perhaps a different SE

Comment: alright, I just thought that _if_ anyone knew what does exists then it would be the people around here that have to do with law on a daily basis..

Comment: It seems to me that questions about how one goes about performing a legal task, such as writing a contract, should be on topic here, although better answers might be obtained on a different SE site.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because recommendation questions are not allowed on any stack.

Comment: This may be on topic on Software Recommendations

Answer (score 3):

A contract is normally simply a text document, and any software that can produce text is suitable for writing a contract. This would include general-purpose word processor software. In some cases a contrat might include tables or diagrams, and then software that can create those features would be desirable.

A contract does not need to be in some highly specialized or specific format that would require something like LaTeX, and many contracts are written on whatever word-processor the drafter has installed on an office computer. But one could use LaTeX if one chose to.

In some fields there is specialized software that includes pre-written sections of contract language, and can produce a finished contract when the user enters information specific to the occasion. For example, there is software that produces a residential lease given the names and addresses of the parties, the rental amount, the address of the rental dwelling, and other relevant information. Such software is generally quite specific to a jurisdiction, such as a country, province or state. The quality of the output varies, and in general such software should only be used for fairly routine situations.

Comment: thanks for your answer, this actually helps me